# Electric skillet probe control burnt at end

Tags: skillet

I'm wondering if it's normal for the end of the probe of an electric skillet to look a little burnt and misshapen (used it twice). (Not asking if it's safe but wondering if others have seen this before).

[image]

I'm asking because I've looked online at other electric skillet control probes online and they look a little burnt too. The company said it's not normal and to return it which I probably will do but I wonder if I get another one will it happen again.

Comment: Also posted in Home Improvement stack exchange.

Comment: They said it was off topic.